# How to show only the div with id while hiding other divs using CSS only

Tags: css, html, css-selectors

I was trying to parse from a complicated html page, but someone told me a better way is to inject my own css into that html. So I have the following situation:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css"  />
</head>

<body>
<div>

   layer one div

    <div id="center">

        layer two div

        <div>

           layer three div

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see the div with id is sandwiched between a parent div and a child div. 
I wonder if it is possible to hide the parent and child, making the page only show layer two div line. I try doing

```
div { display: none; }

div#center { display: inline;}
```

but without success.

I am using the `indent method` now, thank you for all the help, guys! : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is kind of a hack, but it works:

HTML

```
<div>
   layer one div
    <div id="center">
        layer two div
        <div>
           layer three div
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div { 
    text-indent: -9999px; 
}

div#center { 
    text-indent: 0px;
}

div#center div {
    display: none;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fPdda/2/

Comment: does it work on firefox? I tried it with firefox just now. it showed nothing.

Comment: @ShaRanShade I updated it. I messed up in my fiddle. Its still a hack, but does get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no option to show element which is placed under hidden element. So CSS will not do the trick. The only possible option is use javascript, which move element which is supposed to be visible out of parent. This can be easily done with jQuery.

However I don't know why you need this and what you mean with word "parse". CSS will affect only what you see, but under "parse" I understand processing data - and for processing is not important how it is shown. Maybe if you specify more detailed what you need, I can help.

Comment: js and Jquery, that will be my last resort.

Comment: OK, I will write it for you, but tell me if you need keep position of visible div on screen.

Answer (score 0):

This method will not work. Sadly, because your displayed div is inside a hidden div, you're sunk if you're stuck with that markup. You could get fancy and use text-indent: -9999px instead of display: hidden, then text-indent: 0px on the one you want to show, but the negative indented elements will still take up vertical space. Alternately, you could use JS to duplicate the node and re-insert it into the DOM at a different point, maybe inside an element that isn't hidden.

```
var nodeToShow = document.getElementById('center').cloneNode();
nodeToShow.setAttribute('id', 'centerClone');
document.body.appendChild(nodeToShow);
```

Comment: that is a good way to do it, but I can only use css at this point : (

Comment: If you're stuck with only CSS, I might go with the text-indent method that Jason outlined above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible. Hiding the parent div takes precedence on the child, so your child with id is visible but only in the scope of parent div which is hidden. In order to accomplish what you trying to do just wrap the parent text in a span and hide the span;

```
div span{
 display:hidden;
}
div#center div{
 display:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't hide a parent yet make a child element visible, it just doesn't work that way. I would suggest doing something like this:

```
<div class="layer-one">

   <span class="layer-one">layer one div</span>

    <div id="center">

        layer two div

        <div>

           layer three div

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

.

```
div,
span.layer-one {
    display: none;
}

div.layer-one,
div#center {
    display: block;
}
```